# Removing Strings from a Pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below.

```
DF1 =

sid                 path
 1    '["rome","is","in","province","lazio"]'   
 1    "['rome', 'is', 'in', 'province', 'naples']"
 1     ['N']
 1    "['rome', 'is', 'in', 'province', 'in', 'campania']"
 ....
```

I want to remove all unnecessary characters of the column `path` so the result should look like this:

```
DF2 =

    sid                  path
     1         rome is in province lazio
     1         rome is in province naples
     1                    N
     1         rome is in province in campania
 ....
```

I tried replacing all the unnecessary characters like this :

```
 DF1["path"].replace("[","").replace("]","").replace('"',"").replace(","," ").replace("'","")
```

But it didn't work. I suppose it's due to the entries `["N"]`

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why is `['N']` not quoted? Is it a list containing a string or is it supposed to be `"['N']"`?

Comment: `['N']` is a list in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ast.literal_eval` & `str.join`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame({"path": ['["rome","is","in","province","lazio"]', "['rome', 'is', 'in', 'province', 'naples']", ['N']]})
df['path'] = df['path'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                         path
0   rome is in province lazio
1  rome is in province naples
2                           N
```

Comment: Yup that might work, though a bit of a roundabout way since you apply `list` -> `str` -> `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely read lists output as strings. One way to account for genuine lists is to catch `ValueError`.

Note that, if at all possible, you should try to sort these issues upstream before they reach your dataframe.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'sid': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'path': ['["rome","is","in","province","lazio"]',
                            "['rome', 'is', 'in', 'province', 'naples']",
                            ['N'],
                            "['rome', 'is', 'in', 'province', 'in', 'campania']"]})

def converter(x):
    try:
        return ' '.join(literal_eval(x))
    except ValueError:
        return ' '.join(x)

df['path'] = df['path'].apply(converter)

print(df)

                              path  sid
0        rome is in province lazio    1
1       rome is in province naples    1
2                                N    1
3  rome is in province in campania    1
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `ast.literal_eval` and plain `eval`?

Comment: @BubbleBubbleBubbleGut, Yes, `eval` is unsafe and not recommended.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!